How to Implement Free Trials for Monthly and Yearly Subscriptions in iOS Using RevenueCat?
I am implementing a subscription-based app with monthly and yearly plans. I've set up free trials for both plans under Introductory Offers in Apple Store Connect. However, I'm unsure how to integrate these free trials into my iOS app using RevenueCat.
Here are the specific points I need help with:

How do I configure RevenueCat to recognize and handle the free trials I've set up in Apple
Store Connect?
Are there specific methods or API calls in RevenueCat I should use to verify the free
trial period for a user?
Do I need to make any additional configurations in RevenueCat or my app's code to ensure the
free trial works correctly for both subscription plans?

Any examples, documentation references, or guidance would be greatly appreciated.


https://www.revenuecat.com/docs/subscription-guidance/subscription-offers ?

Set Up RevenueCat in Your Project, Install the RevenueCat SDK via pod 'RevenueCat' and read the documentation https://www.revenuecat.com/docs/subscription-guidance/subscription-offers
